# Insertar datos (ID) en oracle desde PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy intentando insertar datos en una base de datos de oracle.

El problema esta en el ID de la tabla.En mysql se hace con auto_increment pero desde oracle con secuencias.
Este es mi codigo del insert:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO usuarios (iduser, nombre, apellido,correo,passwd,codigo,activacion) VALUES(:iduser, :nombre, :apellido, :email, :passwd, :codigo, :activacion)');

        $activacion = 1;
        $id = $stid->lastInsertId();

        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':iduser', $id);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':nombre', $user);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':apellido', $apellido);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':email', $email);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':passwd', $pass);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':codigo', $aleatorio);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':activacion', $activacion);

        $r = oci_execute($stid);



        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close($conn);
```

El problema esta aqui:

```
$id = $stid->lastInsertId();
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on resource in

Como puedo conseguir el ultimo id de la tabla ,sumarle uno y insertar el valor?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes algun error?  Que valor tiene `$id`?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on resource in

Comment: Hola @francisco, el problema no lo tienes en `$stid->lastInsertId()`, lo tienes en la llamada a `oci_parse()`. Ha fallado, por lo que `$stid` vale `false` (booleano), de ahí el error. Además, `lastInsertId()` se usa para averiguar el ID generado automáticamente durante el último `INSERT` y no para conocer cuál es el que debes poner tú en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es crearte una secuencia y trabajar con ella. Esta manera de trabajar es mucho más eficiente que buscando el último ID insertado y sumandole uno.

Comment: En oracle tengo una secuencia para hacer que el id valla auto incrementando,como puedo llamar a la secuencia desde el php?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo ejecutando una consulta del siguiente tipo:
    select mi_secuencia.nextval from dual;
y capturando el valor devuelto

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es :

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conexionbasededatos);
```

---

Tu ejemplo sería así:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO usuarios (iduser, nombre, apellido,correo,passwd,codigo,activacion) VALUES(:iduser, :nombre, :apellido, :email, :passwd, :codigo, :activacion)');

$activacion = 1;
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); //solo he cambiado esta linea

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':iduser', $id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':nombre', $user);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':apellido', $apellido);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':email', $email);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':passwd', $pass);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':codigo', $aleatorio);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':activacion', $activacion);

$r = oci_execute($stid);



oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: Espero que te haya servido, para cualquier otra cosa puedes comentarme, estaré encantado de contestarle.

Answer (score -1):

En Oracle no existe :

```
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Debes hacerlo con un `select max(id) from table`. y allí lo muestras.